# unable to create new file in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was trying to create a new python3 file in colab. But I ran into this error:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please check the browser and browser version that you are using.

You'll likely need to upgrade your browser to one that supports TextEncoder.

See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=textencoder

Comment: hi how do you upgrade the edge browser?

Comment: Edge doesn't work. You'll need to use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.